# transaction confirmation problem

Tags: transactions, mining, contract-deployment, hash

I sent several times some transactions via a consortium established on ethereum (https://energyweb.org/), but none of are mined or confirmed (it is cheched from here : https://tobalaba.etherscan.com/). What might be the reason ?

When I check transaction hash by web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt(transaction hash), it retuns zero. I tried several times to deploy a contact in this way, however I did not get transaction hash.

Consensus mechanism is proof of authority.

Comment: You'll need to provide more details: which client? which consensus algorithm? Are miners/sealer up and running?

Comment: @ivicaa I added complementary info in my question.